# Encrypting Scripts for Embedding in Text Files

Tags: encryption, encoding, scripting

I'm working on a closed-source game that uses a scripting language for automation. Almost all of the game logic is handled by scripts. Scripts can be compiled to a bytecode format, but due to the nature of the language, identifiers must be preserved. Compiled scripts can be embedded in other text-based resource formats using a binary-to-text encoding.

I want to encrypt the compiled scripts to protect the source during distribution, but because the language, bytecode format, and binary-to-text encoding scheme are all proprietary, do I need to worry about encryption at all? If so, should I simply perturb some bytes and call it a day, or should I make use of a fully featured encryption solution? Encryption should not increase the size of the executable unduly, because scripts can be large and load times are important.

Comment: No C++ content I can see - removed the C++ tag.

Comment: Sorry. Tag was added by force of habit because the implementation language is C++.

Comment: Protect the source from what exactly? And why? Where does the idea that you need to use encryption come from?

Comment: I needed to protect the source from being viewed by a person with the intent to reverse-engineer or modify the gameplay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, the size of the executable has no impact on load times because the exe is just mapped into memory and then paged in as needed.  I can't imagine why that would not be true for *nix as well.

So, if the scripts don't need to change separately from your .exe, you could imbed them into the .exe, that would make them difficult for users to change even if they could find them. I wrote a little tool once that turned data files into .obj files that made it really easy to imbed data into my exe - it turned out to be pretty easy to write an object file that contains only data.

Of course, if you *really* care about protecting this data than full encryption in your only choice, but if you are just trying to discourage casual hacking, making the files hard to get at might be good enough.

Comment: Good enough is good enough. I guess some naive perturbation and judicious use of `objcopy` are my solution. And by the way, I was referring to the size of the script executable, not the game application. :)

Comment: @Jon: yes, I see that now.  As I understand it strong encryption doesn't usually grow the data it encrypts so much as round its size up to match the chunk size of the encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't assume that people can't read binary proprietary formats. There are many people who are very good at reverse-engineering protocols without any documentation.

So if you want to keep your source safe, you need some real security. The only problem is that if you encrypt the files, you'll need to give your users the decryption key in order to play the game, and when you do that then its only a matter of time before someone works out how to get the key and use it to decrypt all the files.

So basically, there's not much you can do unfortunately. You could try obfuscating your code, but even that's not going to stop everyone.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about isn't going to be encryption, because you're going to have to ship the decryption key with it. It's just obfuscation. No matter how much you try to hide the decryption key, if your program can find it, so can the user.

So once you understand that we're just talking about various obfuscation schemes, the question is how much obfuscation you need. Likely the proprietary byte-compiling is a higher barrier than the encryption would be, and I'd call it a day. Anyone who wants to trace the logic can just put a debugger on it whether you encrypt or not. If they've already reverse-engineered your run-time engine to work out the byte-codes, then they're already in the portion of the code that has the unencrypted data.

That said, if you find the identifiers in the file to be problematic you can mechanically converts them to random strings prior to byte-compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption would not buy you much here.

Basically, whatever encryption layer you add, the executable itself must be able to perform the decryption in order to run the scripts. You lock the door, but you leave the key in the lock. This is unavoidable.

What encryption does is that it somewhat raises the bar on who may access the data. It requires some disassembly skills. Simply embedding the files in the executable will already filter out the casual not-very-good hacker. Those who are not deterred by such embedding are also those who will be able to follow the data processing path, find the decryption logic, and siphon out the decrypted code at will. A layer of encryption may also increase the feeling of importance: that which was encrypted is certainly worthwhile. Hence, trying too funky things may just make your situation worse, not better.

On the other hand, embedding the files in the executable binary is probably a good idea. It would remove the need to locate them at runtime on the filesystem (locating things at runtime is known to be somewhat more difficult on Unix systems than on Windows, because of hard links: on Windows, an executable can easily obtained its own path, but on Unix the presence of hard links means that "the" executable path is ill-defined).